# Undefined Control Sequenced in Proof

Tags: undefined

I have error : Undefined control sequence for this code, however I am not sure which part is wrong.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}\label{lemma:R5_R6}
\begin{proof}

Besides place and transition which relate to the robot movement, $P^R_k$ and $T_k$, circuit $R_5(A^{\prime}_X)$ and $R_6(A^{\prime\prime}_X)$ are formed by $A^{\prime}_X$ and $A^{\prime\prime}_X$, respectively, for $X \in S$. Since $y= n$ where $n$ is an odd number, then $X \equiv \{x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n\}$ means the circuit connects all activities places for $i=1,\dots,n$. By following the Definition \ref{def:A_prime}, circuit $R_5(A^{\prime}_X)$ where $A^{\prime}_X \equal \{P_{x_1}^{\prime},  P_{x_2}^{\prime\prime},P_{x_3}^{\prime},\dots,P_{x_n}^{\prime}\}$ connects all cleaning place $c_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$ together with the respective $P^R_k$ and $T_k$. Similarly, according to the Definition\ref{def:A_doubleprime}, circuit $R_6(A^{\prime\prime}_X)$ where $A^{\prime\prime}_{X} \equiv \{P_{x_1}^{\prime\prime}, P_{x_2}^{\prime},P_{x_3}^{\prime\prime},\dots,P_{x_n}^{\prime\prime}\}$ connects all processing place $p_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$ together with the respective $P^R_k$ and $T_k$. Therefore, the Lemma \ref{lemma:R5_R6} holds. 
 
\end{proof}
\end{lemma}


\end{document}
```

However, when I recompile the overleaf with compiler pdfLaTeX, the result comes well as follows.

[image: result]

This is the snippet of the error message.

[image: error]

So, is there anyone could suggest what is wrong with the code, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Can reproduce on TeXlive 23 and Overleaf pdflatex 2022. Must have been updated - what is your local TeX version? What error do you get, the `lemma` error or another? Could you edit your error message into the question please

Comment: HI @JamesT, I edited the error message into the question. Secondly, how to check the local TeX version? Right now, I write the code in www.overleaf.com.

Comment: `proof` should not be used inside `lemma`, but *after* it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the code you pasted works as a standalone only if you remove the lemma and proof environments.

Second, your error is the use of `$\equal$` I'm guessing instead of `$\equiv$`. That is where the "undefined control sequence" is.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
    

            
            Besides place and transition which relate to the robot movement, $P^R_k$ and $T_k$, circuit $R_5(A^{\prime}_X)$ and $R_6(A^{\prime\prime}_X)$ are formed by $A^{\prime}_X$ and $A^{\prime\prime}_X$, respectively, for $X \in S$. Since $y= n$ where $n$ is an odd number, then $X \equiv \{x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n\}$ means the circuit connects all activities places for $i=1,\dots,n$. By following the Definition \ref{def:A_prime}, circuit $R_5(A^{\prime}_X)$ where $A^{\prime}_X \equiv \{P_{x_1}^{\prime},  P_{x_2}^{\prime\prime},P_{x_3}^{\prime},\dots,P_{x_n}^{\prime}\}$ connects all cleaning place $c_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$ together with the respective $P^R_k$ and $T_k$. Similarly, according to the Definition\ref{def:A_doubleprime}, circuit $R_6(A^{\prime\prime}_X)$ where $A^{\prime\prime}_{X} \equiv \{P_{x_1}^{\prime\prime}, P_{x_2}^{\prime},P_{x_3}^{\prime\prime},\dots,P_{x_n}^{\prime\prime}\}$ connects all processing place $p_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$ together with the respective $P^R_k$ and $T_k$. Therefore, the Lemma \ref{lemma:R5_R6} holds. 
            

    
    
\end{document}
```

If you, instead, wanted an equal sign, then a simple `=` should do the trick.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
    

            
            Besides place and transition which relate to the robot movement, $P^R_k$ and $T_k$, circuit $R_5(A^{\prime}_X)$ and $R_6(A^{\prime\prime}_X)$ are formed by $A^{\prime}_X$ and $A^{\prime\prime}_X$, respectively, for $X \in S$. Since $y= n$ where $n$ is an odd number, then $X \equiv \{x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n\}$ means the circuit connects all activities places for $i=1,\dots,n$. By following the Definition \ref{def:A_prime}, circuit $R_5(A^{\prime}_X)$ where $A^{\prime}_X = \{P_{x_1}^{\prime},  P_{x_2}^{\prime\prime},P_{x_3}^{\prime},\dots,P_{x_n}^{\prime}\}$ connects all cleaning place $c_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$ together with the respective $P^R_k$ and $T_k$. Similarly, according to the Definition\ref{def:A_doubleprime}, circuit $R_6(A^{\prime\prime}_X)$ where $A^{\prime\prime}_{X} \equiv \{P_{x_1}^{\prime\prime}, P_{x_2}^{\prime},P_{x_3}^{\prime\prime},\dots,P_{x_n}^{\prime\prime}\}$ connects all processing place $p_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$ together with the respective $P^R_k$ and $T_k$. Therefore, the Lemma \ref{lemma:R5_R6} holds. 
            

    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Korne. I use '=' instead of $\equal$ and it works.